# Google Spreadsheet/Calendar Interface Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a Google Spreadsheet (with form) which uploads events to a Google Calendar and sends an e-mail to the form's submitter with additional information. I haven't have any issue with the e-mail portion however the calendar interfacing is giving me trouble.

When I try to run my script it gives me the error message: "Cannot find method (class)until(string). (line 84, file "Code")" The point of this line is to create a calendar event using the data from the submitted form.

Here are the definitions for the line 84 variables (declared elsewhere in the script):

```
var calId = "5u6ui0kdehtpn5ml5gr9s13260@group.calendar.google.com"; //test calendar ID
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId); //sets the active calendar to calID for adding events
var eventTitle = row[11] //"Event Title" column
var eventStartDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[12]), "GMT", "MM/dd/yy") //"Calendar Start Date" column
var eventEndDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[13]), "GMT", "MM/dd/yy");  //"Calendar End Date" column
var eventDescription = "a string for the description"
```

Here is line 84:

```
cal.createAllDayEventSeries(eventTitle, eventStartDate, CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().until(eventEndDate),{description:eventDescription});
```

Any ideas as to why I am receiving this error or what I can do to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're providing the wrong type for a method.

When you check the documentation for the `RecurrenceRule.until()` method, you'll find that the parameter is expected to be a Date object. In your code, you're providing a String, which contains text representing a date. The interpreter hits `.until(eventEndDate)`, and attempts to locate a version of the method that accepts a String parameter, fails, and throws the error you see.

When you're assigning a value to `eventEndDate`, you want it to be a Date object. That means you can just do away with the `.formatDate()` bit, which is only making a pleasant-looking string. Try this instead:

```
var eventStartDate = new Date(row[12]) // "Calendar Start Date" column
var eventEndDate = new Date(row[13])   // "Calendar End Date" column
```

Comment: Thanks Mogsdad, that did it. I forgot that the output from Utilities.formatDate() is a string. I'll make sure to double check the return types next time.